# cast TObject using his ClassType?

Tags: delphi, tobject

how can i make my code to work ? :) i`ve tried to formulate this question but after several failed attempts i think you guys will spot the problem faster looking at the code than reading my 'explanations'. thank you.

```
setCtrlState([ memo1, edit1, button1], False);
```

_

```
procedure setCtrlState(objs: array of TObject; bState: boolean = True);
var
  obj: TObject;
  ct: TClass;
begin
  for obj in objs do
  begin
    ct := obj.ClassType;


    if (ct = TMemo) or (ct = TEdit) then
      ct( obj ).ReadOnly := not bState;        // error here :(

    if ct = TButton then
      ct( obj ).Enabled:= bState;        // and here :(

  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be easier to use RTTI instead of explicit casting, ie:

```
uses
  TypInfo;

setCtrlState([ memo1, edit1, button1], False);

procedure setCtrlState(objs: array of TObject; bState: boolean = True);
var
  obj: TObject;
  PropInfo: PPropInfo;
begin
  for obj in objs do
  begin
    PropInfo := GetPropInfo(obj, 'ReadOnly');
    if PropInfo <> nil then SetOrdProp(obj, PropInfo, not bState);

    PropInfo := GetPropInfo(obj, 'Enabled');
    if PropInfo <> nil then SetOrdProp(obj, PropInfo, bState);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

You must explicitly cast object to some class. 
This should work:

```
 procedure setCtrlState(objs: array of TObject; bState: boolean = True);
 var
   obj: TObject;
   ct: TClass;
 begin
  for obj in objs do
  begin
    ct := obj.ClassType;

    if ct = TMemo then
      TMemo(obj).ReadOnly := not bState
    else if ct = TEdit then
      TEdit(obj).ReadOnly := not bState
    else if ct = TButton then
      TButton(obj).Enabled := bState;
  end;
end;
```

This can be shortened using "`is`" operator - no need for ct variable:

```
 procedure setCtrlState(objs: array of TObject; bState: boolean = True);
 var
   obj: TObject;
 begin
   for obj in objs do
   begin
     if obj is TMemo then
       TMemo(obj).ReadOnly := not bState
     else if obj is TEdit then
       TEdit(obj).ReadOnly := not bState
     else if obj is TButton then
       TButton(obj).Enabled := bState;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Shouldn't second typecast in each case be "TEdit" instead of "TMemo"?

Comment: +0.5 for saying you have to perform casts to each kind. +0.5 for using "is"

Comment: i fixed the typo mentioned by Argalatyr

Comment: Also, I think you have an extra "end;" in each block - better indentation would make this more obvious.

Comment: @Ian: I think you missed the second one

Comment: Thanks for spotting errors in code. I fixed: TMemo -> TEdit and removed extra "end;".

Answer (score 4):

You need to cast the ct object to a TMemo/TEdit/TButton before you can set properties on the object.

The line where you're getting errors are erroring because ct is still a TClass, not a TButton/etc.  If you cast to a TButton, then you'll be able to set enabled to true.

I recommend reading up on [casting in Delphi](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2007/qt/is_as_cast.htm).  Personally, I would recommend using the as/is operators instead of using ClassType, as well.  The code will be simpler in that case, and much more understandable.

---

Personally, I would write this more like:

```
procedure setCtrlState(objs: array of TObject; bState: boolean = True);
var
  obj: TObject;
begin
  for obj in objs do
  begin
    // I believe these could be merged by using an ancestor of TMemo+TEdit (TControl?)
    // but I don't have a good delphi reference handy
    if (obj is TMemo) then
        TMemo(obj).ReadOnly := not bState;

    if (obj is TEdit) then
        TEdit(obj).ReadOnly := not bState;

    if (obj is TButton) then
        TButton(obj).Enabled := bState;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to cast to TMemo and TEdit separately, as they are both descendants from common parent class, which have ReadOnly property:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);

  procedure P(const Obj: TComponent);
  begin
    if Obj is TCustomEdit then
      TCustomEdit(Obj).ReadOnly := True;
  end;

begin
  P(Memo1);
  P(Edit1);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid referencing various units and the explicit casting if you do not mind a small performance hit and limit the changes to published properties. Have a look at the TypInfo unit included with Delphi.